# Merge list of tiff files to one using python

Tags: python, tiff

I am tryin to merge list of tiff files to one. I can add 2 tiff files but not sure how to add list of tiff files. please help.

````
input1 = tifftools.read_tiff('sample1.tiff')
input2 = tifftools.read_tiff('sample2.tiff')
# Add input2 to input1
input1['ifds'].extend(input2['ifds'])
tifftools.write_tiff(input1, 'output.tiff')

print('Merger Done') ```

how can I add if I have a list of tiff file ex.
``` tff_lst=['a.tif','b.tif','c.tif','d.tif'] ```
````

Comment: Are you trying to make one list with all the tiff files in it or a list inside another list?

Comment: one list with all the files and then want to merge them for example. I have a list of tiff file tff_lst=['a.tif','b.tif','c.tif','d.tif'] , want to merge them in same order

Comment: If you have two different lists, list1 and list2, you can easily make a new one containing all the elements by doing list1 + list2. Pass that one as input write_tiff. I have not worked with tifftools. So, i do not know what kind of input it accepts. But if it is just a single list, then this should help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just read the first tiff file and then loop over all the others in the list, reading them and extending the first:

```
tff_lst=['a.tif','b.tif','c.tif','d.tif']
tff = tifftools.read_tiff(tff_lst[0])
for other in tff_lst[1:]:
    othertff = tifftools.read_tiff(other)
    tff['ifds'].extend(othertff['ifds'])
tifftools.write_tiff(input1, 'output.tiff')
```

Comment: getting error for one of the tiff file it's saying not a known header for c.tiff. how can i fix it?

Comment: Try to read that file alone: does it work? If not, then chances are your file is corrupted, or contains some advanced tags not recognized by tifftools.

Comment: yes, reading alone is not working giving same error

Comment: To check if it is corrupted you can try to open it in a simple image editor, like MS Paint on Windows. And to check if it is too advanced for `tifftools` there are a few online "tiff tag editor" where you can see if the file giving error has some tags that do not appear in the other files - if that is the case you will need to switch to another library (`libtiff` perhaps?)